# My android xml code is not displaying two texts properly

Tags: android, android-layout

my code is displaying the two different texts one over the other while i want them to be one above the other. I am providing my code in relative layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="hello im Shailly"
    android:textColor="#B82525"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nexttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="32dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/intro"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:text="and i'll show you around this app"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    />
```

Comment: what do you mean with properly? How it should be displayed? Can you show some examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/intro"
```

aligns the bottom edge of `nexttext` with the bottom edge of `intro`.

You should use:

```
android:layout_below="@id/intro"
```

so that `nexttext` is placed below `intro`.

Comment: no i just did it because it appeared first :|

Answer (score 0):

You need this line of code in your second TextView

```
android:layout_below="@+id/intro"
```

So your code looks like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="hello im Shailly"
    android:textColor="#B82525"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nexttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/intro"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:text="and i'll show you around this app"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    />
```

you may remove:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/intro"
```